# How do I tell Entity Framework to use SQL Server Compact in code first?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-ce

How do I change my app.config or Migration Configuration.cs file so Entity Framework uses a local SDF file instead of a local SQL Server instance ?  I am using EF 6.1.

Thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<configSections>
 <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit      http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
<section name="entityFramework"type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <entityFramework>
  <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory,  EntityFramework" />
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient"   type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
</providers>
</entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just be able to specify the ProviderName in the connection string to your database.

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DataModelContext"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"
     connectionString="Data Source=location\cfdb.sdf"/>
```

Comment: And install the EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact nuget package

Comment: Yep, I shouldn't have assumed that.